# Retrieve json object as querystring using wcf Restful Service

Tags: c#, javascript, json, wcf

i am creating a WCF Restful service in which i want save the json object coming from the javascript as querystring  by POST operation..I am getting the json object as querystring but can't access it in wcf restful, please help..........

> My javascript code

```
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();


myRequest.onreadystatechange=function(dataString) {

    if (myRequest.readyState == 4 && myRequest.status == 200) {


        console.log('Sent to server: ' + dataString + '');
        window.localStorage.removeItem(dataString);
    }
    else if (myRequest.readyState == 4 && myRequest.status != 200) {

        console.log('Server request could not be completed');
        saveDataLocally(dataString);
    }
}
    var url="http://localhost:58168/RestServiceImpl.svc/json";
myRequest.open("POST",url+"?"+dataString,true);
    myRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    myRequest.send(dataString);

   alert('Saved to server: ' + dataString + '');
```

> My Request in javascript
>
> ![while sending the json object as querystring to wcf restful server][1]

```
>**RequestURL**:http://localhost:58168/RestServiceImpl.svc/json?"firstName":"shuresh","lastName":"kumar"}
```

> **Request Header:**
>   Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   Origin:chrome-extension://ddijiilbgbjgciahjmonfahapadmkcfp
>   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
>
> **Query String Parameters**
>   {"firstName":"shuresh","lastName":"kumar"}:
>
> **Form Data**
>   {"firstName":"shuresh","lastName":"kumar"}:

WCF Restful service contract

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "json?dataString={dataString}")]
    string JSONData(string dataString);
```

> RestServiceImpl.svc.cs

```
  public string JSONData(string dataString)
    {

        return "You requested product " + dataString;


    }
```

I can't access the json object(dataString) in the service contract.please help me how to access the json object that is append in the querystring in the wcf restful above code.

```
http://localhost:58168/RestServiceImpl.svc/json?"firstName":"shuresh","lastName":"kumar"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't push everything in under "one string".

Try this (just to show the concept)

```
public string JSONData(string firstNameArg)
    {
//your code here
}
```

and then

```
http://localhost:58168/RestServiceImpl.svc/json?"firstNameArg":"shuresh"}
```

and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

On POST/PUT the Form Data is not in QueryString, instead, you could find it in the InputStream of the request. 
Also, your QueryString have not correct format...?param=value&param=value...
Hope it helps you